# How to enable Delete button in PHP when Admin is logged in but not for Viewer (normal user)?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a simple report viewer, where PDF's stored in a folder are displayed in the table and can be opened when user clicks on it. That thing is working fine. I also have a Upload functionality which lets the user upload the files to the respective folders and later can be displayed in the table. I also can delete the files by showing a delete link right in front of the file name in table.

At first, I wanted there to be only one user which could do all the things. Now, we want the Delete link and Upload menu to be displayed only when the username is 'Admin'. We do not want to use any databases, because data is not so classified and we are fine using a script based solution. However, I can't figure out how to enable Delete and Upload only for Admin. The code I am using is attached below:

**From login.php**

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

    /* Check Login form submitted */
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        /* Define username and associated password array */
        $logins = array('reader' => '123456','admin' => '654321','username2' => 'password2');


        /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable */
        $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
        $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

        /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */
        if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
            /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
            $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
            header("location:index.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
            $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Before every page, we insert this code:**

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */
 if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
   header("location:login.php");
   exit;
 }
 ?>
```

**And this is what we are doing inside the table to display list of files and a link to delete them:**

```
foreach($files as $file)
        {
                  if(isset($_GET['delete']))
                  {
                    unlink($file);
                    break;
                    //a better approach for deletion will be appreciated
                  }

          echo'<tr><td><a href="ViewerJS/#.'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.returnFile($file).'</a></td>
          <td><a href="'.$file.'">Download</a></td>
          <td><a href="?delete=1">Delete</a></td>

          </tr>';
        }
```

Comment: based on your code `if($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'] == 'admin'){echo "<td><a href="?delete=1">Delete</a></td>";}`

Comment: note, its not working... its not displaying another cell with the required Delete link..

Comment: echoing $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']; is giving me 654321, which is password of Admin.
So its not exactly username its gonna compare, lol, this is funny :D

Comment: Why don't you use cookies?

Comment: You should store the user name in $_SESSION['UserData']['Username'] and not the password

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I changed `$_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];` into `$_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$Username;` in login.php.

Finally adding `if($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'] == 'admin')` before any code I wanted to appear only when Admin is signed in. Thank you everyone.